# How to not take Null values while doing table calculation but keep them for the aggregated total

Tags: tableau-desktop

**Background**:

I have a cohort analysis table that shows month of year on the Y axis (Rows) and Difference from next month as my X axis (columns). With Customers as my measure, you see values from 0 to 12 on the column side, showing all the conversions from that particular month and people who did not make a conversion are shown as Null.

**Problem**:

As I have a table with column showing Null, 0,1,2... 8 showing values, and the total of this shows me my cohort size. So as a customer, Null is important as it shows the size of the total group. But I want to have a percentage of each group and show the cumulative growth of the group without taking the null group.

**Summary**

I want to show a cumulative percentage growth but not take my first column (that is the null values) but keep it to have the totals show correct value.

The following image can help you understand
For January 2022,

1. You have the total value of each column
2. You see the individual percentage of that column/ total
3. You see the cumulative percentage growth total
   Result to see: if we can do cumulative percentage total without taking the Nulls.

**Follow up Clarification from Image:**

```
The expected answer should look like this
For 0 --> 3.9%
For 1 --> 7.8% (3.9%+3.9%)
For 2 --> 9.5% (3.9%+3.9%+ 1.7%)
```

As you can see, the percentage value takes the total cohort size and shows the 3.9%,which is the correct value and doing cumulative by excluding the Null value % that is 87.1% (therefore hiding the Null value column)

[image: Tableau Sheet]